# I'm trying to write a simple script in google sheets, that reads an ID number from a list and outputs the name associated to it

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to write a simple script in google sheets, that reads an ID number from a list and outputs the name associated to it. Essentially like an attendance list. 
I'm sure its a very simple script but I've been stuck on it for a while. 
I've tried using If statements, Array Formulas but I can only get it to work on the top line of the column and with only one ID number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on Sheet1

- column A = ID
- column B = asociated name

on Sheet2

- column A = ID
- column B = output

try in Sheet2 cell B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; Sheet1!A2:B; 2; 0)))
```